# Почему после стандартной сборки vagrant на сайте puphpet.com не работает php?

Tags: php, apache, vagrant

После стандартной сборки виртуальной машины для vagrant на сайте PUPHPET не работает php . Сборка: apache, php . Файлы сборки брал отсюда: https://yadi.sk/d/GlEHNyfxcbDgw

В итоге апач работает, все без ошибок, но при попытке вызвать php файл выводится так:

[image: скриншот1]

При попытке вызвать команду `php -v` выводит

[image: скриншот1]

Кто-нибудь знает в чем может быть дело?

Comment: Апач не настроен на обработку php. Либо кода php вообще, либо файлов с расширением php, phtml. Нужен конфиг апача

Comment: Еще хорошо бы логи со старта вагранта.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

возможно, не подключен молуль для *php*.

как его подключить в используемой вами кастомной сборке — должно быть написано в прилагающейся документации.

---

а в дистрибутивах, основанных на *debian*, в случае пакетов *apache2* и *libapache2-mod-php5*, установленных из репозитория дистрибутива, для включения/отключения модуля можно воспользоваться такими командами:

```
$ sudo a2enmod php5
$ sudo a2dismod php5
```

после чего необходимо будет перезапустить *apache*.

Comment: да, ясно что проблема с модулем, вопрос в том, почему это модуль не загружается, используя настройки с  https://puphpet.com/ . Это баг сайта или у меня

Comment: смотрите в логах.